# iOS Custom keyboard - Not able to move focus to and fro between custom keyboard's search field and the third party app’s search field

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard, uikeyboard, custom-keyboard

We are designing a custom keyboard on iOS with a TextField (Search Field) on it.

Problem - Not able to move the focus to and fro between our custom keyboard's search field and the third party app’s search field.

[image]

when the focus comes to the custom keyboard search field it never goes back to the Parent App's  search field.

PS: I have seen the keyboard apps like Popkey and Fleksy successfully doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find out a workaround to achieve required functionality by keeping a Label instead of textField. With this work around we don't have to worry about the focus issue. Once user starts typing, we need to catch the event and update the text in label.

Hope this will help if some one is still looking for a solution to this problem.